# PHP : Getting only first record from database in array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

i am trying to fetch database on the basis of posted values.This is a property website and one col named attr has json data. this is how i am fetching  data

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
  $proptpe = $_POST['proptype'];
  $q= mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM properties");
  $savemyval = array();

  while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
     $data = json_decode($row['attr']);

     if($proptpe == $data->proptype) {
         $savemyval[] = $row['id'];
     }

     $myquery = '';
     foreach($savemyval as $arr){
         $myquery.= '`id`  = '.$arr.' OR ';
     }

     $myquery = rtrim($myquery, " OR ");

     $type = $_POST ['optionsRadios'];
                if(isset($_POST['unit_type'])){
                    $unit_type = $_POST['unit_type'];
                }

                else {
                    $unit_type = '';
                }
                $min_price = $_POST['min_price'];
                $max_price = $_POST['max_price'];
                $min_bedroom = $max_bedrooms = '';
                if(isset($_POST['res_min_bed'])){
                    $min_bedrooms=$_POST['res_min_bed'];
                }
                else{
                    $min_bedrooms='';
                }
                if(isset($_POST['res_max_bed'])){
                    $max_bedrooms = $_POST['res_max_bed'];
                }
                else{
                    $max_bedrooms='';
                }
               if(isset($_POST['com_min_size'])){
                   $min_size=$_POST['com_min_size'];
               }
               else{
                   $min_size='';
               }
               if(isset($_POST['com_max_size'])){
                   $max_size=$_POST['com_max_size'];
               }
               else{
                   $max_size='';
               }
                $query= "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE 1=1"; 
               if($type != ""){
                 $query.=" AND type= '{$type}'";
               }
               if($unit_type!=""){
                $query.=" AND  unit_type='$unit_type'";
               }
               if(($min_price!="") && ($max_price!="")){
                $query.=" AND  price BETWEEN {$min_price} AND {$max_price} ";
               }
               if($proptpe){
                   if($myquery != ''){
                       $query.=" AND ".$myquery;
                   }
               }
               if($min_bedrooms != "" && $max_bedrooms != ""){
                   if($myquery != ''){
                       $query.=" AND ".$myquery;
                   }
               }
               if(($min_size!="") && ($max_size!="")){
                    $query.=" AND size BETWEEN {$min_size} AND {$max_size}";
               }
               if($query==FALSE){
                   echo mysqli_error($connect);
                   die;
               }
               else {
                    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
               }
               echo $query; 
               die;
       }
```

when i print query i get only first record from database for commercial type , for residential type i get all the vailable records  ,

if i do print_r for posted values this is what i get

```
Array
(
    [optionsRadios] => sale
    [unit_type] => 
    [min_price] => 
    [max_price] => 
    [res_min_bed] => 
    [res_max_bed] => 
    [proptype] => commercial
    [search] => Search
)
```

> Array ( [0] => 42   ) SELECT * FROM properties WHERE 1=1 AND
>   type= 'sale' AND `id` = 42

Need your help with this please

Comment: Please indent your code properly as it makes it easier to read.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: what's the problem? your query  where clause has id=42 so it's returning one row only.

Comment: It's worth noting that an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) make querying like this significantly easier. Even better there are [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) which help organize your code better. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is very beginner friendly and has a wealth of community code for ad-hoc searching.

Comment: Sikander if one of the answers helped you, please select it (and upvote if you wish). It takes time to research, test and write up these answers.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is the following:

```
 For all database records
    If proptype is what you selected in form then
        Accumulate ID in array savemyval
    Immediately loop through savemyval
        Generate some SQL
    ...
    die() statement
```

Few issues here:

1. You are exiting on first main loop
2. You're generating SQL on same loop where you're accumulating ID's
3. ID's shouldn't be accumulated in this manner. Why not use SQL to do all this?
4. Create class(es) with some meaningful methods and do a separation of concerns. It's not straightforward to see understand what you're trying to do. Data Retrieval, SQL generation, Search logic and controller logic shouldn't be in one loop.
5. Escape POST values properly. As tadman mentioned, SQL injection is a problem in that code

Comment: I'm with you up to the `die` part. There's no reason to call that in properly written PHP code. It's an extreme measure.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to start over; this code is poorly constructed and has many errors.  If you want to go ahead and try to patch it, I am pasting my feedback below:

There are lots of problems with your code. I caught some of them but there may be more.

You have no separation between your `OR` and `AND` clauses when you attach `$myquery` to `$query` with the following line:

```
$query.=" AND ".$myquery;
```

You should wrap the different sections in parentheses.  Instead of writing the IDs part of the query as `id=1 OR id=2...`, use `id IN (1,2...)`

Replace:

```
foreach($savemyval as $arr){
    $myquery.= '`id`  = '.$arr.' OR ';
}
$myquery = rtrim($myquery, " OR ");
```

With:

```
$myquery = "`id` IN (".implode(",",$savemyval).")";
```

Later you have this line:

```
$min_bedroom = $max_bedrooms = '';
```

I think you mean the plural `$min_bedrooms`.

Later you add `$myquery` to `$query` twice. I'm not sure why:

```
if($proptpe){
   if($myquery != ''){
       $query.=" AND ".$myquery; // append $myquery here
   }
}
if($min_bedrooms != "" && $max_bedrooms != ""){
   if($myquery != ''){
       $query.=" AND ".$myquery; // do the same here??
   }
}
```

I think you meant to have something like `AND bedroom BETWEEN $min_bedrooms and $max_bedrooms`.

Still later you write:

```
if($query==FALSE){
   echo mysqli_error($connect);
   die;
}
```

I don't get why would it ever equal `false`? At this point `$query` is just a string; you never executed the query. Do you mean this?

```
if(mysqli_query($connect,$query)===false) die(mysqli_error($connect));
```

Anyway that's just a taste. Again my advice. Start over.